# asp.net nested views with owns controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a target to create a nested architecture of view/controller. For example:
we have few areas in webpage. All this areas managed by its own controller. In another words I need to create independend pages and then join them in one page.
Please see the image: [image]

So is it possible and where I can read about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html.Action()` to render child views from different controllers

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}

public class SecondController : Controller
{
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult Method1()
  {
    return PartialView();
  }
}

public class ThirdController : Controller
{
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult Method2(int ID)
  {
    return PartialView();
  }
}
```

Index View (FirstController)

```
....
@Html.Action("Method1", "Second")
@Html.Action("Method2", "Third", new { ID = someValue })
```

You can also use `@{ Html.RenderAction();` which is more efficient is you are generating a lot of html.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this by simply calling

@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");

**Example:**

in your case you can do like this

**Controller1**

```
 public ActionResult View1()
    {

        return View("View1");
    }
```

**Controller2**

```
 public ActionResult View2()
    {

        return View("View2");
    }
```

**Controller3**

```
 public ActionResult View3()
    {

        return View("View3");
    }
```

---

**Calling in main page:**

```
@Html.Action("View1", "Controller1");
@Html.Action("View2", "Controller2");
@Html.Action("View2", "Controller2");
```

call these in different section of main page wherever you want.